# Tikz Antenna Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to draw these antenna diagrams.

[image: Antenna Diagrams]

My approach is using kind of a parametric curve like this:

```latex
\documentclass[convert = false, border=5pt]{standalone}
\input{../common/settings.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw plot[
          variable=\t,
          domain=0:360,
          smooth,samples=51
      ] 
    ({20*sin(\t)}:{6*pow(0.95*sin(\t/2),5)});
  
   \draw plot[
          variable=\t,
          domain=0:360,
          smooth,samples=51
      ] 
    ({180+30*sin(\t)}:{0.8*pow(sin(\t/2),5)});

  \draw(-1.2,0) node[] (A) {};
  \draw( 5.1,0) node[] (B) {};
  
  \draw[] (A.east)  -- (B.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Yagi Antenna]

Has somebody an idea how to describe the curves of these two pictures with such a kind of parameter curve?

Comment: You might also ask here to see what the real shape (formula) is: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you another approach, I'm not sure if it can help. I'd draw the antennas combining circles (first one), ellipses (second one) and clips (both).

Something like the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\i in {1,2,3}
{
  \begin{scope}[rotate=120*\i-150]
  \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0:2);
  \clip (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (60:4) -- (120:2);
  \draw (60:0.5) circle (1.5);
  \end{scope}
}
\draw[thick,fill=white] (0,0) circle (1mm);
\fill                   (0,0) circle (0.5mm);

\begin{scope}[shift={(7,0)},scale=0.8]
\foreach\i/\j in {1/1,1/-1,-1/1,-1/-1}
{
  \begin{scope}[x=\i cm,y=\j cm]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[rotate=60*\i*\j] (1.62,-0.6) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
  \end{scope}
 }
\draw[thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]